# getopts arguments picks next arguments as parameter

Tags: bash, getopts

What if there are multiple options provided in getopts and some require arguments while some do not? getopts arguments picks next arguments as parameter

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b:cde:f:g:" opt; do

case $opt in
  a)
    echo "-a was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  b)
    echo "-b was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  c)
    echo "-c was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  d)
    echo "-d was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  e)
    echo "-e was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  f)
    echo "-w was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  g)
    echo "-g was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  \?)
    echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
  :)
    echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
done
```

Here's my problem:

```
$ ./hack.bash -a -b 
-a was triggered, Parameter: -b
```

Shouldn't it display that -a is missing an argument instead of taking the next option as the parameter. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `-b` is considered an argument to option `-a`, so the behavior you see is normal.

Answer (score 0):

If a command line option takes an argument, that argument must be supplied, so it is correct and expected that `getopts "a:b"` will parse `-a -b` as the option `-a` with argument `-b`. Otherwuse, there would be no way to provide an argument starting with a dash. (Remember that shell strings are, as in other programming languages, just arrays of ordinary characters. The fact that a character was quoted when it was entered in a shell command line does not change the internal representation of the character, so `-` and `\-` are not distinguishable.

Some older command-line utilities do provide a mechanism for optional option arguments. The Posix guidelines on parsing arguments strongly discourage that style, but the utilities which do that generally predate the guidelines. In any case the guidelines are just that -- guidelines, not rules. `getopts` does not help with that style of argument parsing because it is designed to work within the guidelines; in sime sense, to help maintain them.

Long options, whose arguments are conventionally separated from the option name with an `=`, do not have this problem; `--long=-a` is clearly a value, while `--long -a` is clearly a `--long` with no value followed by the option `-a`.